# Phalcon Multi module common model magic getter not working

Tags: php, model, phalcon, multi-module

I'm using Phalcon PHP with multi modules structure and I want to use a magic getter on my object but the getter is null when I'm trying to do a var_dump.

**Snippet Model Users**

```
namespace Apps\Common\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Users extends Model{

   public $id;

   public $city_id;

   public $name;

   ...

   public function initialize(){
       $this->belongsTo("city_id", "City", "id");
   }
}
```

**Snippet Model City**

```
namespace Apps\Common\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class City extends Model{

   public $id;

   public $name;

   ...

   public function initialize(){
       $this->hasMany("id", "Users", "city_id");
   }
}
```

**Magic getter utilization**

```
public function addAction() {

  $user = Users::findFirst(array(
    "id = :id:",
    "bind" => array('id' => 2)
  ));

  city = $user->getCity();  // This is null

  echo city->name;

}
```

Do you know why this magic getter `$user->getCity();` doesn't work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have to define the namespace and an alias in the relation like this :

```
namespace Apps\Common\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Users extends Model{

   public $id;

   public $city_id;

   public $name;

   ...

   public function initialize(){
       $this->belongsTo("city_id", "Apps\Common\Models\City", "id", array('alias' => 'City') );
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I know but I have to wait 2days to accept my answer